# Change Java temporary internet files storage location

Tags: java, caching, java-web-start

I am trying to change the storage location of Java Web Start. I read that the location is changeable through the java control panel. I got there and I can see the path of my "temporary internet files" but the "change" button is gray. Why can't I change this path? I need to change it to another hard drive.

Comment: I suggest this is moved to [superUser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [googled](http://www.google.com/) it for you.

This was my search phrase:

> java console change temporary location

And this was the result that was most appropriate:

[How to change Cache location for Java on windows 7](http://iambiased.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/how-to-change-cache-location-for-java-on-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks, I googled it for about an hour and did not find anything useful. Maybe I used the wrong terms ...

Comment: It looks like on Windows 10 only second method works from the link above, i.e. properties file editing.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Find javacpl.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31("newest version")\bin*javacpl*

**Step 2**
Right click on javacpl than Properties---Compatibility---choose 
run this program in compatibility mode for “Windows XP SP3″

**Step 3**
Go to
  Control panel--Java--General--Setting--Location and Change it.

**P.S.** Close java control panel before step 1 if its open.