# Java 7u65 and 7u67 windows webstart cache path error (Could not load file/URL specified)

Tags: java, java-web-start

A user reported the following error trying to start an application via WebStart on Windows 7:

```
Could not load file/URL specified: C:\Users\HÃ¶fn\AppData...
```

The Windows locale is Iceland and the 'Language for non-Unicode programs' setting is Icelandic. Note the Windows username is supposed to be "Höfn", but the "ö" character looks corrupted in the error message so it seems the path can not contain unicode characters.

The application worked fine prior to the latest Java update.

I tried deleting the Java cache but the problem persisted.

**I solved the problem (temporarily) by uninstalling the latest Java update and installing JRE 7 update 60.**

I figured more people would run into this problem and require a temporary solution.

Comment: Is this on Windows XP?  Have you noticed that Oracle have dropped support for Windows XP as of Java 7u65?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it was Windows 7, edited to include... and no I had not noticed that, interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem starts with Java 7u65 as it is present on all later Java versions including 7u67 and 8u11. I submitted [bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8054904).

While we wait for Oracle to fix this, here are three things we can do:

**Workaround one: (only works for Java < 7u65)**

1. Go to Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Administrative (Advanced) ->  Language for non-Unicode programs
2. Set "Current language for non-Unicode programs" to any language that uses Unicode letters.

**Workaround two: (works for all - Change Java temporary path of user)**

1. Create new directory for example C:\TempJava\ASCII_USERNAME (without Unicode letters inside path name)
2. As changing Java temp path inside Windows7 is disabled in Java Control Panel, there is [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169384/change-java-temporary-internet-files-storage-location/16169686#16169686):

   - Open file %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
   - Add line: deployment.user.cachedir=C:\TempJava\ASCII_USERNAME
   - Save and try to run JNLP again

**Workaround three: (works for all)**

1. Create user with account name in ascii text (without multi-byte letters)
2. Start JNLP from that account

Comment: I had a chance to test this on a Windows 7 machine and the 'Language for non-unicode programs' was Icelandic, which is correct.

Comment: @darri You can create user account on Windows machine with character set ISO8859-5 (Cyrillic alphabet). If you login into that account and use ISO8859-1 (Western Europe) as Systems locale, you won't be able to run applications that need System Locale in order to encode correctly user home path (for example).

You must check if account name characters are written in Language inside _Language for non-unicode programs_.

Comment: I really appreciate your input, I'll take a better look at this in the next few days. It's rather tempting to call this a bug in Java, simply due to the fact that this wasn't a problem until 7u65.